# class not found in java reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I'm learning java reflection. I am using the following code. But when I run, it gives the error

> unreported exception ClassNotFoundException; must be caught or
>   declared to be thrown
>   Class className=Class.forName("First");

Maybe I'm going wrong somewhere. Please help me out. Here's the code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
public class First{   
        public void print(){}
        public void ready(){}
    }

public class test{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Class className=Class.forName("com.Test.First");
        Method[] methods=className.getMethods();
        System.out.println("First method is" + methods[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: It means exactly what it says.  You must either add `throws ClassNotFoundException` to your `main` method, or you need to enclose the statement which is generating that compilation error in a `try` block which is followed by `catch (ClassNotFoundException e)`.

Comment: thanks VGR. got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All it's saying is that Class.forName throws this (non-runtime) Exception so you must handle it somehow. Here are two ways you could do it

```
public class test{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
        Class className=Class.forName("com.Test.First");
        Method[] methods=className.getMethods();
        System.out.println("First method is" + methods[0]);
    }
}
```

Or

```
public class test{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try {
          Class className=Class.forName("com.Test.First");
          Method[] methods=className.getMethods();
          System.out.println("First method is" + methods[0]);
       }
       catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is the problem

```
Class className=Class.forName("com.Test.First");
```

in the `Class.forName("com.Test.First")`, you can replace `com.Test.First` with any gibberish and the compiler shouldn't care enough to validate it for you. All the compiler knows is that it is possible for there to not be a class `com.Test.First` and therefore you are responsible for handling a `ClassNotFoundException`.